# Why are all of my all-day events on my iPad on the wrong date?

Tags: ipad, ios, icloud, ical, calendar

All of my all-day events are a day "early" on my iPad. This applies to all-day events I have entered manually, birthdays (which I can edit indirectly through the Address Book), and synchronized calendars from Apple (e.g., US Holidays). For events that I can edit, doing so corrects the problem (though even that would require hundreds of edits to individual events), but I can do nothing about synchronized calendars. Events in Lion Calendar, iCloud, and my iPhone calendar are on the correct dates.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or found a way to correct it?

Comment: Have you checked the date and time-zone settings on your iPad?

Comment: @ClareMacrae: Yes, those are correct and the same ("Set Automatically") as on the iPhone (where the issue is not present).

Comment: To expand Clare's question, does it change anything if you set the time zone manually? (i.e., set it to Central, Eastern, etc. instead of using "Set Automatically")?